# Convert DataFrame to dict

Tags: python, pandas

I have been searching a long time on the Internet but to no avail.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

unames = ['user_id', 'gender', 'age', 'occupation', 'zip'] 
users = pd.read_table('ml-1m/users.dat', sep='::', 
header=None,names=unames,engine='python')
rnames = ['user_id', 'movie_id', 'rating', 'timestamp']
ratings = pd.read_table('ml-1m/ratings.dat', sep='::', 
header=None,names=rnames,engine='python')
mnames = ['movie_id', 'title', 'genres']
movies = pd.read_table('ml-1m/movies.dat', sep='::', 
header=None,names=mnames,engine='python')
data=pd.merge(pd.merge(ratings,users),movies)
```

then I get a table like this:
[a DataFrame of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guZhf.jpg)

then, I processed the data like this

```
data1=pd.pivot_table(data[(data.user_id==1)],index=['title'],columns='user_id',values='rating')
```

the output:
[a DataFrame of the data1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mls3V.jpg)

then I try to convert the `data1` to a dict

```
Dict=data1.to_dict()
```

the dict is like this:

```
{1: {'Airplane! (1980)': 4,
 'Aladdin (1992)': 4,
 'Antz (1998)': 4,
 'Apollo 13 (1995)': 5,
 'Awakenings (1990)': 5,
 'Back to the Future (1985)': 5,
 'Bambi (1942)': 4,
 'Beauty and the Beast (1991)': 5,
 'Ben-Hur (1959)': 5,
 'Big (1988)': 4,
 "Bug's Life, A (1998)": 5,
 'Christmas Story, A (1983)': 5,
 'Cinderella (1950)': 5,
 'Close Shave, A (1995)': 3,
 'Dead Poets Society (1989)': 4,
 'Driving Miss Daisy (1989)': 4,
 'Dumbo (1941)': 5,}}
```

however, I want to convert the `data1` to a dict like this:

```
{'Airplane! (1980)': 4,
 'Aladdin (1992)': 4,
 'Antz (1998)': 4,
 'Apollo 13 (1995)': 5,
 'Awakenings (1990)': 5,
 'Back to the Future (1985)': 5,
 'Bambi (1942)': 4,
 'Beauty and the Beast (1991)': 5,
 'Ben-Hur (1959)': 5,
 'Big (1988)': 4,
 "Bug's Life, A (1998)": 5,
 'Christmas Story, A (1983)': 5,
 'Cinderella (1950)': 5,
 'Close Shave, A (1995)': 3,
 'Dead Poets Society (1989)': 4,
 'Driving Miss Daisy (1989)': 4,
 'Dumbo (1941)': 5,}
```

the difference is that the first version has an `1` as key, so how can I convert like the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select by name of column `1` for `Series` and convert to `dict`, also better is change variable name `Dict` like mentioned @jpp in comments:

```
d = data1[1].to_dict()
```

Comment: there is a error: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 2 elements

Comment: @L.Ying - Sorry, answer was changed

Comment: I soved，Thanks!!

Comment: emmm, I'd like to konw what the meaning of "1" in data1[1]?